# Populate LinearLayout by external layout file

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I created a drawer layout with LinearLayout as main content layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <!-- The main content view -->
    <ScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/scroll_wrapper" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" >


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/white"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:background="#FFF"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Now as is there are no Views under LinearLayout is it possible to create a layout in external file `main_layout.xml` and then call that xml in this LinearLayout defined in my DrawerLayout above.

The reason for this is that I am building the UI programatically so when user selects an option from my DrawerNavigation menu I call `content_container.removeAllViews();` then I read a JSON schema and populate the content_container with Views defined in JSON. However when user goes back to the home page again I need it to load the default static views from my `main_layout.xml`

This way I don't have to programatically build the home layout/views.

Answer (score 0):

These links may be helpful depending on your goal,  [LayoutInflator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html), [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html), [Include](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

Answer (score 0):

> Now as is there are no Views under LinearLayout is it possible to create a layout in external file main_layout.xml and then call that xml in this LinearLayout defined in my DrawerLayout above.

Your question isn't 100% clear but I'm assuming you want to dynamically create an XML file in internal or external storage and then inflate it as a layout.

If that's the case then the answer is no, you can't do this. Even though there is an API method allowing the use of a path to an XML layout file to my knowledge it was never implemented and won't work.

Layout files are pre-processed at build time in order to make layout inflation efficient and reduce processor / GPU load. The only way you can create layouts at runtime is to do it programmatically in-memory.

Comment: Ok to clear up what I need. I created a DrawerLayout that has LinearLayout inside it this is for the main content now if I add any views to this then as soon as I open my app I will see these views.  

Now when I drag out the menu from DrawerLayout and click on one of the options I need to replace the main content or basically show an new layout that is build based on JSON schema file. I have this working but since my navigation options call LinearLayout.removeAllViews() I loose the views I had on main layout when I loaded.

Comment: I have a home button in my menu that should restore that initial layout/views that were show when application was loaded.

Comment: @kellax : It seems to me you'd be better off using a `FrameLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout` and use `Fragments`. The default `Fragment` would use your `main_layout.xml` layout file but then you'd replace that with another `Fragment` which programatically creates another view from your JSON schema. When you go back from the second `Fragment` you'd simply have to show the first which uses `main_layout.xml`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with LinearLayout since I have a package of classes all build for building a UI from JSON schema on top of a vertical linear layout.  

When I first started I used FrameLayout but the problem was that each new View I added was placed on top of the previous one with vertical LinearLayout each new one is placed bellow in a new line.

Comment: Maybe any way I could create a XML file containing TextView.. etc elements then in my main activitys onCreate method populate the LinearLayout with that XML file same for on click for the home button ?

Comment: You're misunderstanding the point about using a `FrameLayout` with `Fragments`. The `FrameLayout` would be the container for the `Fragments` but the second `Fragment` which you either add to the `FrameLayout` or replace the previous `Fragment` would have your `LinearLayout` in it. That said, what you are describing as far as putting `TextViews` in lines (rows) sugests you should just be using a `ListView`.